# C++ sendto() gives "invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int, int, int)throw ()’ to ‘int’" error

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I've been trying to solve this weird problem for the past weeks but no success.

Basically I'm trying to send a message to an endpoint over UDP, and I'm using the `sys/socket.h`

Below is the code that is giving me error.

```
sendto(socket, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &endpoint, 
       sizeof(endpoint));
```

Where `endpoint` is a `sockaddr_in` struct.

And the compiler complains:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int, int, int)throw ()’ to
>   ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

It's funny because the file is a group project and there are other parts of the code that is using exactly the same code as above, and the compiler is happy with those. Only when I copy paste the line to the function that I'm writing in the same file it gives me this error.

I couldn't think of a reason why this could happen. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Besides, I'm compiling with `-std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic`

Comment: Please post an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `socket()` function with three `int` parameters,
and the compiler thinks you want to pass it as first parameter to `sendto`.

Apparently you have a variable `socket` somewhere too, "hiding" the socket function, but not in this scope, so it takes the function. Stop calling the variable `socket`, then it will be easier to find out (and calling the `socket` function in parts where the variable is known will be less problematic too)...

Comment: LOL what a stupid mistake...cuz the function was split into 2 lines and the compiler shows the second line number so I always thought it was the ```sizeof``` that's giving me error but it doesn't match the type in the error...anyway, solved.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler thinks that you are passing a pointer to the `socket` function in the first argument to `sendto`, try changing the variable name.